# How do you copy data from a JSON file in a external stage in Snowflake when the file is too large?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JSON file (well technically several) in an external GCS stage in Snowflake. I'm trying to extract data from it into tables, but the file is too large. The file doesn't contain an array of JSON objects, but it actually one giant JSON object. As such, setting `STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY` to `true` isn't an option in this case. Breaking the files into smaller files isn't really an option either because they are maintained by an external program and I don't have any control over that.

The general structure of the JSON is:

```
{
    meta1: value1,
    meta2: value2,
    ...
    data: {
        component1: value1,
        component2: value2,
        ...
    }
}
```

The issue is due to the value of `data`. There can be a varying number of components and their names aren't reliably predictable. I could avoid the size issue if I could separate out the components, but I'm unable to do a `lateral flatten` inside of `copy into`. I can't load into a temporary variant column either because the JSON is too large. I tried to do an `insert` instead of a `copy`, but that complains about the size as well.

Are there any other options? I wondered if there might be a way to utilize a custom function or procedure, but I don't have enough experience with those to know if they would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

So its external programs to GCP to Snowflake. Looking at all the things you have tried around snowflake, seems like there may not be any other option available within SF.. However, how about checking something at GCP end. Once the file reaches GCP say in Folder 1, try to split the JSON into smaller bits, and move them into GCP Folder 2. Create your external stage on top of Folder 2.

Even I do not have much idea on GCP but thought of sharing this idea in case it works out for you.

Comment: I was worried that might be the case...

Answer (score 0):

> I could avoid the size issue if I could separate out the components,
> but I'm unable to do a lateral flatten inside of copy into.

I think you can use LATERAL FLATTEN in a CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ... statement ([see this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009UvBNDSA3/is-it-possible-to-flatten-json-using-copy-command)). You leave your huge JSON file in an external stage like S3, and you access it directly from there with a statement like this, to split it up by the "data" elements:

```
create table mytable (id string, value variant) as
  select id::string, value::variant
  from @mystage/myfile.json.gz,
    lateral flatten(input => parse_json($1:data));
```

Comment: This seems to have the same problem. I tried it out and I got "100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: document is too large, max size 16777216 bytes". It's almost like it's trying to temporarily store it as a variant before even loading it in, but variants have the 16 MB size restriction.